# Interchanging IN with EXISTS produces different result sets

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, execution-plan, query-performance

I am attempting to update a query that utilizes the `IN` operator within a `WHERE` clause predicate with `EXISTS` to compare potential performance improvements and better understand what is happening behind the scenes when the two are interchanged. It is my understanding that in practice, the query optimizer treats `EXISTS` and `IN` the same way whenever it can.

I'm noticing that when the query is ran with the `IN` operator, it returns the desired result set. However, when I replace it with the `EXISTS` equivalent, it pulls in all values from the primary table I want to filter. It is ignoring the provided input values passed to `EXISTS (SELECT ...` and returning all possible distinct values.

The use case is relatively straightforward: the query accepts a pipe delimited `@Series` string that can contain up to 4 values, e.g. `S1|S2|S3|S4` or `S2|S4`. From here I `string_split` the input into a table variable `@SeriesSplit` to determine the corresponding internal `[SeriesId]` for the `[Series]`. The result set returned is then filtered to exclude the `[Series]` that were not passed.

To illustrate, here is a similar table definition:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[Document]
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Document]', 'U') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document] (
        [DocumentId] bigint IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        ,[DocumentSeriesId] [tinyint] NOT NULL
        ,CONSTRAINT [PK_Document] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DocumentId] ASC)
        ,INDEX [IX_Document_SeriesId] NONCLUSTERED ([DocumentSeriesId] ASC)
    );
END;
GO
```

Populate the test table with dummy data.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Document] ON;
;WITH [DocumentSeed] AS (
    SELECT
        1 AS [DocumentId]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        [DocumentId] + 1
    FROM
        [DocumentSeed]
    WHERE
        [DocumentId] < 2048)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] ([DocumentId], [DocumentSeriesId])
SELECT
    [DocumentId]
    ,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 4) + 1
FROM
    [DocumentSeed] OPTION (MAXRECURSION 2048);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Document] OFF;
```

First, the query that utilizes the `IN` operator and returns the desired results.

```
-- Specify the Document Series to be returned.
DECLARE @Series varchar(12) = 'S1|S2'
-- Split the user input and insert it into a table variable.
DECLARE @SeriesSplit table ([SeriesId] tinyint, [Series] varchar(2))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @SeriesSplit ([SeriesId], [Series])
SELECT
    CASE [value] WHEN 'S1' THEN 1 WHEN 'S2' THEN 2 WHEN 'S3' THEN 3 WHEN 'S4' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS [SeriesId]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM([value])) AS [Series]
FROM
    string_split(@Series,'|')
WHERE
    [value] <> ''
END;

-- Return the result set of desired [DocumentSeriesId]
-- In the real use case, DISTINCT is not used and more columns are returned.
-- However, to illustrate the issue at hand, return only the [DocumentSeriesId] as this is what we are filtering off.
SELECT DISTINCT
    D1.[DocumentSeriesId]
FROM
    [dbo].[Document] D1
WHERE
    D1.[DocumentSeriesId] IN (SELECT SS.[SeriesId] FROM @SeriesSplit SS)
```

The outputs two rows as desired. [The execution plan (PasteThePlan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByvWEnfjf) shows it performing a `Distinct Sort` to filter the appropriate rows.

If I change the `WHERE` clause to utilize `EXISTS`, I am greeted with all four possible outcomes *even though I have set to return only two.*

```
-- Specify the Document Series to be returned.
DECLARE @Series varchar(14) = 'S1|S2'
-- Split the user input and insert it into a table variable.
DECLARE @SeriesSplit table ([SeriesId] tinyint, [Series] varchar(4))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @SeriesSplit ([SeriesId], [Series])
SELECT
    CASE [value] WHEN 'S1' THEN 1 WHEN 'S2' THEN 2 WHEN 'S3' THEN 3 WHEN 'S4' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS [SeriesId]
    ,LTRIM(RTRIM([value])) AS [Series]
FROM
    string_split(@Series,'|')
WHERE
    [value] <> ''
END;

-- Return the result set of desired [DocumentSeriesId]
-- In the real use case, DISTINCT is not used and more columns are returned.
-- However, to illustrate the issue at hand, return only the [DocumentSeriesId] as this is what we are filtering off.
SELECT DISTINCT
    D1.[DocumentSeriesId]
FROM
    [dbo].[Document] D1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT SS.[SeriesId] FROM @SeriesSplit SS JOIN [dbo].[Document] D2 ON SS.[SeriesId] = D2.[DocumentSeriesId])
```

[The execution plan (PasteThePlan)](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Byu4B2zoG) is vastly different with this small change. It is tossing a warning that there is `No Join Predicate` within the `Left Semi Join` predicate. It was my assumption that `WHERE EXISTS ...` would implicitly satisfy this argument as it does with `WHERE [DocumentSeriesId] IN ...`. However, given that the `Left Semi Join` operator returns each row from the initial input when there is a matching row in the second input, and because the `No Join Predicate` warning exists, query optimizer assumes that each row is a matching row. Therefore all subsequent batch operations are ran against all 2048 rows in the table.

What can I look into to better interpret what the execution plan is describing so that I can understand how to properly resolve the issue?

Or, alternatively, am I simply missing the purpose of the `EXISTS` operator when filtering result sets based on a static input?

Comment: `(IN results) <> (EXISTS results) => (there are NULLs involved)` Or the query was not properly rewritten, as it is the case here ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ If I'm understanding, if there are NULL values, then the operators will not evaluate the same. However, in this case, there are no NULL values.

Comment: yeah, the Nulls are usually a problem with NOT IN / NOT EXISTS rewrites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't rewrite the query properly. When converting an `IN` subqquery to an `EXISTS` one, your `EXISTS` subquery should be correlated. But you defined the `Document` table again in the subquery, making it uncorrelated.

Your query basically says

> Give me all data from `Documents` if `@SeriesSplit` has at least one row - and nothing if `@SeriesSplit` is empty.

It should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    D1.[DocumentSeriesId]
FROM
    [dbo].[Document] D1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @SeriesSplit SS 
            WHERE SS.[SeriesId] = D1.[DocumentSeriesId]) ;
```

Comment: Is there a `DocumentSeries` table? If there is, you could use it, in place of `Document` and get better performance (smaller table + avoids the `DISTINCT`)

Comment: All that time spent trying to interpret the execution plan when the issue was an incorrect subquery. Bah! It makes so much more sense now. Thank you for the concise answer to my overly verbose question that I overthought. There is indeed a `[DocumentSeries]` table that is joined to in the much larger query. The `DISTINCT` here was to return the questionable result sets. The full query does not utilize `DISTINCT`. Thank you, sir!